# How to inject a JavaScript function and its call from text area?

Tags: php, javascript, html, code-injection

How can I submit a function definition and its call from

```
<input type="text">
```

tag?

EDIT:
My friend have written a php script where he takes the value of  tag and without calling strip_tags function prints on another page. Now I want to show an example with JavaScript (I believe it should be possible) that I can inject a JavaScript code into his website. That is my task.

Comment: What? You mean you want to enter the text of the function into the text input?  Hopefully not to `eval()` it later... ? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: My friend have written a php script where he takes the value of <input type="text"> tag and without calling strip_tags function prints on another page. Now I want to show an example with JavaScript (I believe it should be possible) that I can inject a JavaScript code into his website. That is my task.

Comment: I believe @Narek, wants to compromise his 'friends' website by doing javascript injection, and he wants our help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke script from your textbox, try to use `eval` in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Invoke()
    {
        var ctrl = document.getElementById('content')
        eval(ctrl.value);
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="content" />
<input type="button" onclick="Invoke()" value="Invoke" />
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/AuPRM/

Answer (score 0):

Assign the return value of `yourFunction.toString()` to the `value` property of the field.